# Push git tags from Azure Pipeline to GitHub

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline that I would like to push git tags on my `master` branch to GitHub when a build succeeds. I see lots of documentation about triggering pipelines by pushing tags, but not pushing tags *from* a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you can [run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with Azure script, all you would need is:

```
git push --follow-tags origin master
```

This uses [`--follow-tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---tags) in order to push only the relevant tags.